# C#: Unable to assign Image to PictureBox image source path from text file in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to display image in a `PictureBox` dynamically. Image source is stored in a text file. When reading the image path from the file it keep showing image error symbol. When I include the path in the code it works.

Text file line sample

> F01,Nasi Lemak,RM 2,@"Food\NasiLemak.jpg"

```
public void readData() 
{
    try
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("food.txt"))
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(',');
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, part);
                {
                    Label LblFId = new Label();
                    {
                        //LblFId.AutoSize = true;
                        LblFId.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
                    }
                    Label LblFName = new Label();
                    {
                        LblFName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
                    }
                    Label LblFPrice = new Label();
                    {
                        LblFPrice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 20);
                    }

                    PictureBox foodPicBox = new PictureBox();
                    {
                        foodPicBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 200);
                        foodPicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        foodPicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

                    }
                    Panel fPanel = new Panel();

                    LblFId.Text = parts[0];
                    LblFName.Text = parts[1];
                    LblFPrice.Text = parts[2];
                    foodPicBox.ImageLocation = parts[3];

                    fPanel.Controls.Add(LblFId);
                    fPanel.Controls.Add(LblFName);
                    fPanel.Controls.Add(LblFPrice);
                    fPanel.Controls.Add(foodPicBox);
                    foodFlow.Controls.Add(fPanel);


                }
            }
            i++;

        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code???

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: You should read about [MCVE]

Comment: edited..i write my code & one line of my text file

Comment: @February Does it work if your text file is formatted without `@` and `"` (quote), like this: `F01,Nasi Lemak,RM 2,Food\NasiLemak.jpg`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the path from the text file

```
@"Food\NasiLemak.jpg"
```

This should be saved like without the @ and the "

```
Food\NasiLemak.jpg
```

Or you should write more code to remove those symbols like this

```
foodPicBox.ImageLocation = parts[3].Replace("@", "").Replace("\"", "");
```

This will remove the samples and your problem would be solved.

You need also to close foreach statment at this point

```
foreach (string part in parts)
        {Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, part);}
```

Comment: Another question I wanna ask. Why my image repeating 4 times. Can you let me know?

Comment: Just close foreach statement after the Writeline to solve the repeating problem